# Replace existing images to Photo Album

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum() method to save images in photo library.I am calling webservices to get images and saving it in photo library but It is creating copy of images because webservice is calling no. of time.
How can I replace existing images from Photo Library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can not, since this will allow you to update user images with their consent.

Apple is very restrictive about these kind of things, just image you are overwriting all the images by adding some banner. There is noway the user can undo this.

Comment: Can I get photo library path to check whether that image is present there or not?

Comment: Not unless you have stored the path before. How do you intent to check whether it is the same image?

Comment: @DeviPhone26 you can try using [`ALAssestLibrary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to access  photo album.

Comment: I am thinking to check with its URL